# PyCharm console output is adding extra space before each new line

Tags: python, pycharm

I am using Pycharm 2202 on windows 11, the problem is that when I run the app, it adds extra space with the same length of the previously outputted line.
I have "Emulate terminal" enabled.
I tried editing the font of the output console but had no luck.
Here is a screenshot of the output console showing the problem:

[image: PyCharm output console]

Comment: So, you mean this happens only in PyCharm? If you run the code from a console outside what happens ?

Comment: Exactly, only in Pycharm. If I run the code directly from a console, it outputs normally. Also, I noticed that the problem only presences in Pycharm 2022

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1 - Change the console font**:

You can try changing the console font to see if that works for you.  You can do this by navigating to `File` -> `Settings` -> `Editor` -> `Console Font` and then changing the font.

In my case, my font is set to use the `default` which is `JetBrains Mono 13` (the `use console font instead` option is unchecked).

**Solution 2 - Restore default settings**:

If the issue has started occurring recently and the console was displaying correctly before, you can try restoring the default PyCharm settings. You can do this as follows:

`File` -> `Manage IDE Settings` -> `Restore Default Settings`

Note, you will need to restart your IDE.

Comment: I already tried it as I mentioned in my post, didn't change anything though.

Comment: @HussainBiedouh Have you tried restoring the default settings?

Comment: I did, still no luck. Note that the problem seems to be only in Pycharm 2022.